# Approximation of eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, approximation

I'm having trouble with the following problem:

> Let $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ be a Hermitian matrix, $\mu\in\mathbb{C}$, $\epsilon>0$ and $x\in\mathbb{C}^n$ such that $\mid\mid x\mid\mid=1$ and $\mid\mid Ax-\mu x\mid\mid<\epsilon $, then $A$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda$ such that $\mid\lambda-\mu\mid<\epsilon$.

I would like any hints of where to start. I was thinking of using Courant-Fischer, or some of the "spectral inequalities", but I don't know how to proceed.

Thank you.

Comment: The direct approach -- decomposing $x$ in the eigenbasis of $A$ -- doesn't lead anywhere?

Comment: @user7530: It does.  Just assume all $|\lambda_j - \mu| \ge \epsilon$ and estimate $\|A x - \mu x\|^2$.

Comment: @user7530 Yes, that solves the problem.